# Key combination to kill the task using the most processor power

Tags: overheating

Sometimes my laptop starts to overheat caused by the CPU working too hard. It is usually due to a webpage on Chrome. I usually use:

```
$ top -bn1 -o %CPU | head -17
```

to identify and kill the process if it continues too long.

I have read about Alt+SysRq+F combination, which commands the system to kill the task taking most memory, and was wondering if there is a similar key combination to kill the task using the most processor power

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about a sysrq combination for this task, but you can use `top` or `htop` to find the process using the most CPU and kill it with `killall -9 <process>`. If it is possible to use a sysrq combination for this, somebody please correct me. For a complete list of sysrq combinations, check out this article:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key